# Android application to stream local MKV videos to chromecast with subtitles

Tags: android, video-player, chromecast

I have a bunch of .mkv videos and subtitles files on my Android tablet and I want to cast them to my chromecast. I am looking for a video player to cast them.

VLC is able to play all the videos correctly but does not support casting subtitles.

I have tried a bunch of other softwares (MX player, AllCast...) but none of them support playing all the mkv: often the sound is missing (wrong codec ?), or the video cannot be played at all.

Does anyone know an app which could do that ?

Comment: Have you installed the "adapted codec" pack in MX player? Some audio codecs like EAC3 require it to be installed.

Comment: Are subtitles integrated or are external file?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have both

Comment: Check here: https://www.winxdvd.com/play-video/vlc-chromecast-subtitles.htm